# Slow BitmapData.draw() with matrix from camera video

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

Im building an iOS AIR app using AS3/Flash builder.

The app grabs the camera stream into a video object and then draws that to a BitmapData. The camera stream is 1280x720px and the container is 2208x1242px (iPhone 7+) so I need to scale the footage. I also need to rotate it around the center point:

```
mat.identity();
mat.translate(-video.width/2,-video.height/2);
mat.rotate(Math.PI/2);
mat.translate(video.height/2,video.width/2);
mat.scale(deviceSize.height/cam.width,deviceSize.width/cam.height);
```

I have timed the drawing operation with matrix:

```
videoBitmapData.draw(video,mat); //9-11ms
```

And without matrix:

```
videoBitmapData.draw(video); //2-3ms
```

Clearly the transformation is slowing me down.
Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe drawing first, then applying the matrix somehow?
Pre-rotating something?
Leveraging native scaling/rotation?
Can I skip using the video object somehow? Accessing the camera data in a more raw form?

I see no difference using render mode GPU vs CPU.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I managed to get down to about half by doing this:

```
1. Put the video object inside a Sprite
2. Transform the Sprite.
3. Draw the Sprite to the BitmapData.
(5-6ms)
```

Suprisingly, this was more consistent than this:

```
1. Put the video object inside a Sprite 
2. Transform the video object inside the Sprite
3. Draw the sprite to the BitmapData
(5-12ms)
```

**Bonus:**
I only needed part of the pixels from the camera (full width x 100px of the height). When realizing I could use clipRect with the .draw command I managed to get down to 0-1ms.

Thanks to Organis

Comment: Applying transform matrix forces Flash to additionally CPU-render the content you draw. Try having another video object transformed up to your needs inside a Sprite (it does not even have to be attached to display list) and draw the Sprite. That just **might** save these few ms for you (or not). Accessing the raw video data feed... no, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: First of all, thanks. I misunderstood you and tried putting it inside a Sprite, then I transformed the Sprite and finally drew the Sprite. This forced me to draw with the Sprite.transform.matrix but still took me from ~9-10ms to ~5-6ms. Interesting. I will now try to transform the video inside the sprite, maybe that lets me draw without a matrix.

Comment: Okay, now I tried to transform the video inside the Sprite, then drew the Sprite. Getting 5-12ms now, quite randomly. Strange.

Comment: I actually don't need of all the video pixels. Im only interested in a rect with the full with and about 40px of the height. Will cliprect speed up the drawing process?

Comment: Oh yes, so just drawing what I needed from the video object, using BitmapData.draw(videoHolderSprite,null,null,null,clipRect,false); gives me 0-1 ms. Perfection! Thanks Organis

Comment: Glad to know I pushed you to the right direction : )))